# ERROR in ./node_modules/recompose/dist/Recompose.esm.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/extends'

Tags: reactjs, laravel, babeljs, laravel-mix, recompose

I am using laravel(5.6) and reactjs with recompose package. But when I run yarn dev its getting this error:

[image]

My babelrc code here-

```js
{
  "presets": [
    ["env"],
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions",
    [
      "babel-plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": true,
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me why getting this error.

Comment: I jus got this too..CRA with recompose. did you get a solution?

Comment: No I didn't find the solution. I am trying.

Comment: What command are you running? I do not see a 'yarn dev' command in the yarn docs https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/. Perhaps you meant 'yarn install'?

Comment: Its laravel-mix package.json default command for run the webpack. It should compile jsx file with babel but given this error. Its given the error when I use HOC component without extend the React.component class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recompose @0.28.x causing babel build issues; downgraded to 0.27.1

Comment: I have a 0.28.0 that doesn't have any issues though

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to

`import 'babel-polyfill';`

at your application entry point?

The build will fail if you don't.